# Do I need a transit visa for Germany on the way to Canada?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, canada, egyptian-citizens

I’m a new immigrant to Canada. I’m traveling from Cairo Egypt to Toronto via Germany or any other European country with an Egyptian passport and a Canadian visa.

Will I need a transit visa for Germany or Europe? How can I get one in Cairo? How much time will it take?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. It would be best if you could demonstrate what research you have attempted on your own (e.g. contacting the German consulate, calling the airline, even doing a web search). The [Airport Transit in Germany](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) page from Germany.info suggests that no, you do not need a transit visa when traveling on an Egyptian passport.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a transit visa if you remain airside when you transit through Germany. Auswaertiges Amt (the Federal Foreign Office) publishes a list of [countries whose citizens require a transit visa](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html), and Egypt is not on it.

In addition, [holders of a valid Canadian visa or permanent resident card do not need a transit visa at all](http://www.kanada.diplo.de/Vertretung/kanada/en/02/visa/airport__transit__visa.html).

If you must leave the airport, (e.g. your layover is overnight and the airport closes) or your layover is longer than 12 hours, you *will* need [a regular short stay Schengen visa](http://www.kairo.diplo.de/Vertretung/kairo/ar/07__neu/__Allgemeine__Hinweise__zum__Schengenvisum.html).

Comment: (+1) In fact, the list isn't even relevant, there is no scenario under which a Canadian visa holder could require an airport transit visa.